# create panel page template for some taxonomy terms conditionally

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I want to create a panel page template for some taxonomy terms ( not for all ). Most of the taxonomy term page will be on default template ( or custom template ) but some pages I want in panel page template.

Can you guys please give your suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Try things yourself first, and when you get stuck this is the right platform to ask. You should show self initiative first

Comment: I've create custom panel templates first (inside my custom theme folder ) , after that I've created one panel page using that template. After that have given Boolean option which will tell whether you want to display page on panel format. But not getting idea how it will possible to switch once user select that option to yes.

Comment: Could you provide that code? If you do we could help you much better